# typeError Macro Script google sheet Remove editor not define

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Script was running perfect before  1 hr now it has stopped and showing error please help

```
function Dem() {
          var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A910').activate();
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 01'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 02'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 03'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 04'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 05'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 06'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 07'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 08'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 09'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 10'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 11'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 12'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 13'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 14'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 15'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 16'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 17'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 18'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 19'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 20'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 21'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 22'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 23'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 24'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 25'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 26'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 27'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 28'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 29'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 30'), true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day 31'), true);
          if(spreadsheet.getRange('AR5').getValue()=='1');
          var protection=spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];{;
          protection.removeEditors(['ketan.joshi@mountmerugroup.com','chauhan.mayank@mountmerugroup.com']);
        }
        }
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3iRq04OjfnwRNcTuB9sWwyMCgtuVcIkoIICYYH9Dys/edit#gid=1031767026

The same code was running well when it was created in same sheet but now its showing Type error: remove editor cannot read properly
please help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3iRq04OjfnwRNcTuB9sWwyMCgtuVcIkoIICYYH9Dys/edit#gid=1031767026

Answer (score 0):

### Your error most likely means that the spreadsheet does not have any sheet protection

You can verify it e.g. with the line

`protection.getEditors().forEach(function(editor){Logger.log(editor.getEmail())});`

If this line gives you the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditors' of undefined`

you know for sure that there is no sheets protection (and thus it is not possible to get or remove editors).

Comment: Then how the same script ran at time of creation and now error ?

Comment: Maybe the protection or the protected sheet has been removed? You can check manully from the UI either you have any portected sheet or alternatively with `Logger.log("number of protections: " + spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET).length)`. If the result is 0 - you know that you don't have any sheet protections...

Comment: now the sheet is protecting but its not following if(spreadsheet.getRange('AR5').getValue()=='1'); Just protecting all sheets now

Comment: You need to put the code to be executed if the 'if' statement is fulfilled inside of {} brackets. Also, you have `{;` - if it is not a typo accidentally placed when inserting your code into your question - you should remove it.